# How to calculate how much does a set of arrays changes?

Tags: arrays, math

I have a set of arrays that describes a sequence of 3D positions. The structure is:

```
arr[N][0] = X;
arr[N][1] = Y;
arr[N][2] = Z;
```

where N goes from 0 to (total count of 3D-coords - 1).

How can I write a function that, taking a set of N arrays, returns a value from 0 to MAX where:

return value near 0 => the positions are very close together
return value near MAX => the positions have changed a lot.

Is there an algorithm/mathematical function for that?

Comment: Are there any bounds on the values of X, Y and Z?

Comment: I think no, they can be very changeable, also they are signed.

Comment: Say you shuffled all the points so that oldarr[i] is never newarr[i] but you still have the same (multi)set of points, they're simply ordered differently.  Should your metric say there's been a lot of change or none at all?

Comment: Are you saying that you have N sets of N 3D points? That would be N matrices with dimension Nx3. And you want to quantify how much different your N matrices are? I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One measure of scattering is the [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

You can calculate the variance for each coordinate separately and then add them (and doing so should be mathematically correct).